# EventEmitter in Angular 5: why does the child component not change the parent?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5, dom-events

I have child controller:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'select-test',
    templateUrl: 'select-test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['select-test.component.css']
})
export class SelectTestComponent {
  @Input() model: any;
  @Output() public changeModel: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

Html:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="this.changeModel.emit(this.model)" />
```

Parent html:

```
<p>{{testData}}</p>
<select-test [(model)] = "testData"></select-test>
```

Why child component doesn't change parent component variable?

Comment: I believe it's because you are not subscribing to that emission in your parent component.ts

Comment: you dont need `this.`'s on the `this.changeModel.emit(this.model)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

**Component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'select-test',
   templateUrl: 'select-test.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['select-test.component.css']
})
export class SelectTestComponent {
   @Input() model: any;
   @Output() public changeModel: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

**Component.html:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="changeModel.emit(model)" />
```

**Parent.html:**

```
<p>{{testData}}</p>
<select-test [(model)]="testData"></select-test> //TWO-WAY DATA BINDING
<select-test [model]="testData"></select-test> //OR ONE-WAY DATA BINDING
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution.
Need change changeModel name to modelChange.